# Convert an SObject to a custom Object by using its object name

Tags: casting, salesforce, apex

I have a class that is called with multiple different types. I want to convert an SObject into a specific custom object (The object name is provided). Instead of the actual code I will use this snippet below as an example.

```
SObject dynamicObject = [SELECT Id, Term__r.IntegratedFromExternalSystem FROM ParentObjectName LIMIT 1];
```

Now I want to use the Parentobjectname to get the type.

```
SObjectType sObjType = ((SObject) Type.forName(parentObjectName).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
```

This has the type that I want, now I want to convert this Sobject into its custom object, so I can actually retrieve that integratedFromExternal field. Otherwise it says the field will not exist.

Obviously, you cant use variables as types so this will not work, but this is the best way of describing what I want to do. I need to type it based off whatever the ParentObjectName field is. This class is dynamically used in different parts of the system and there is a variety of different custom objects to cast into here.

```
sObjType myCustomObject = (sObjType) dynamicObject;
Boolean integratedFromExternal = myCustomObject.Term__r.IntegratedFromExternalSystem__c;
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried dynamic getters? sobj.get('fieldname') or sobj.getpopulatedfieldsasmap() methods? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24804/799